# Which is the origin of the Spanish verb "tener" in the sense of possession?

Tags: verbos, etimología, significado, historia

Back in the Latin days, the verb that denoted possession was the copulative verb *esse*, a function that it had even in the Old Spanish, as it can be seen in the *Cantar de Myo Çid*:

> *en vuestras manos son las arcas* = the coffers are in your hands (possession) = you have the coffers

In Latin, the verb *tenere* (teneô, -ês, -êre, tenuî, tentum) also existed, but in the sense of holding something, and not in the sense of possession. It seems that this verb *tenere* is what origined the current verb *tener*, as it can be seen in the DRAE:

> **[tener](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZT8sFSB)**
>
> Del lat. *tenēre*.
>
> 1. tr. Asir o mantener asido algo.
> 2. tr. poseer (‖ tener en su poder).

The first meaning is the one inherited from Latin. My question is: when and why did *tener* start to have the sense of possession in Spanish (the second meaning)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el diccionario español-latino de Nebrija de 1495, ya se recoge el término *tener* significando tanto "teneo, -es", como "habeo, -es". Es decir, en el siglo XV ya existía la acepción de "tener" en el sentido de posesión ("habeô, -ês, -êre, habuî, habitum" es el verbo usado en latín para el actual "tener"). Por tanto me fui a buscar un poco más atrás.

En el CORDE aparecen 1421 casos de "tengo" en el siglo XIV, 752 en el siglo XIII y 10 en el siglo XII (también debido a la escasez de documentos de la época). Vamos a analizar algunos casos:

> E agora, a myo sennor dixieron lo que yo fiz, que ascondi .c. prophetas del Nuestro Sennor e las **tengo** en las cuevas e les do a comer.

En este caso parece que "tengo" se usa en el sentido de "las he dejado", más que en el sentido de posesión.

> ¡En grado vos lo **tengo** lo que me avedes dexado!

En este ejemplo "tengo" parece significar "guardar", o incluso "tener en alta estima" ("tener en grado").

> Levedes un portero, **tengo** que vos avrá pro; si leváredes las dueñas, sírvanlas a su sabor.

Aquí parece significar "entiendo que vos".

> ¡Grado al Criador e al Padre espirital, todo el bien que yo he todo lo **tengo** delant!
>
> ¡Grado al Criador e a Santa María madre, mis fijas e mi mugier, que las **tengo** acá!

En estos ejemplos parece significar "estar" ("están delante de mí" y "están a mi lado").

> D'estos tres mill marcos los dozientos **tengo** yo, entr'amos me los dieron los ifantes de Carrión.

Esta es la expresión que más dudas me genera, porque no sé si al decir "los tengo yo" se refiere a que los está sosteniendo en la mano, o si los lleva encima, o si los guarda en su custodia. El caso es que me inclino a pensar que el sentido de posesión del verbo "tener" se pudo iniciar a causa del dinero, algo que se solía llevar encima, que era tuyo y que por tanto poseías. Un ejemplo de 1215 dice:

> Non les daré otro loguero, que yo non **tengo** más d'un dinero.

De ahí pasó a significar posesión de mercancías, como en esta frase de principios del siglo XIV:

> Yo **tengo** un aver de vender, cortés e fermoso.

Otros ejemplos a lo largo del siglo XIV ya incluyen también a la familia (no solamente en el sentido de "estar a tu lado" como en el Cantar):

> ...**tengo** un noble marido, el gentil infante...
>
> ...non **tengo** un maravedí.